# how do I force a page break in Rave Reports, Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rave-reports

I am new to Rave and I'm having a ridiculous amount of difficulty forcing page breaks between sections of my report.  It's a master-detail report, with various types of detail sections (master = patient; detail 1 = visit history; detail 2 = medications etc.).  I've got the detail sections working ok but need to: a) force a page header to carry over on every page and b) force each detail section to start on a new page.  In other words, I want every page of the report to include a header with the patient name, ID etc., and I want each type of data (visits, meds, etc.) to appear as its own section.

I've tried the different Band styles and checkboxes for having the bands appear on every new page, etc., but I can't get a header or a page break for the life of me.

Can anyone provide the settings I should use for the page header band and the bands that should begin a new page with each section?  Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using rave report designer or are you doing a code-based report?

Comment: Hi Warren - using the designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking "New Page (P)" in Band Style Editor should force it to be printed on each page.  If not, maybe verify that the Header band style (Group/Body etc) has the ControllerBand set to the Detail databand of your DataView.

Comment: Jason, thanks so much.  Your second tip was key - and I just realized that the page breaks can be forced by simply putting each section on a separate report Page.  Duh!  Anyway, it's looking better.  Thanks for the quick response.  Edward

Comment: Cool.  Although, you shouldn't have to put each "section" on a separate page.  Setting StartNewPage will (should) force that section to be on a new page.  Again, check your mappings between sections (bands) and confirm ControllerBands/Views etc are set correctly.
Could you also mark this as Answered when you are able to. Thanks